# How to stop file-roller from outputting anything and hanging on the process

Tags: command-line, 17.04, file-roller, stdout

I'm writing a program that uses `file-roller` to extract an ISO file. However I keep getting a warning and I don't want to see this warning. Also `file-roller` hangs after this warning. `Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without transient parent. This is discouraged`. Once this hits, `file-roller` will just hang and not do anything. I'm using `file-roller` through the command line with `file-roller -e <PATH> <ISO IMAGE>`. My question is simple, how can I disable the warnings and the stdout on the command and stop the process from hanging when a warning hits?

Script:

```
def unzip_iso(filepath, verbose=False, directory_name="ISO_dir"):
    """
      Unzip the ISO file into a directory

      :param filepath: the path to the ISO file
      :param verbose: verbosity output
      :param directory_name: the name of the ISO directory
      :return: True if it worked, False if it didn't
    """
    def create_rand_dir_name(chars=string.ascii_letters, verbose=False):
        """
          Create a random directory name
        """
        if verbose: LOGGER.debug("Creating random directory name..")
        retval = set()
        for _ in range(8):
            retval.add(random.choice(chars))
        return ''.join(list(retval))

    dirname = create_rand_dir_name(verbose=verbose)
    if verbose: LOGGER.debug("Creating directory: {}/{}/*..".format(directory_name, dirname))
    create_dir(directory_name + "/" + dirname)
    full_dir_path = os.getcwd() + "/" + directory_name + "/" + dirname
    if verbose: LOGGER.debug("Directory created, full path being saved to: {}..".format(full_dir_path))

    cmd = "file-roller -e {} {}".format(full_dir_path, filepath)
    if verbose: LOGGER.debug("Starting command: {}..".format(cmd))
    stdout_data = subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your script. You can re-direct stdout and stderror in bash. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html  `command &> /dev/null` . Does the command work outside your script ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen let me add the script one second

Comment: Why don't you simply use the right command-line tool to extract the archive? `file-roller` should be able to extract files automatically in the way you describe it, but better use a simple tool for simple things than a general GUI program. For iso, you could either mount the image and copy the files out of it with `cp`, or you install e.g. the `p7zip-full` package and use `7z x /path/to/file.iso`. Actually if you don't have `p7zip-full` installed, that might even be the cause why file-roller is unable to extract the iso. Not sure if it natively can read those without this package.

Comment: @ByteCommander need it to be already installed on the system

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Added to the question

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly get what you wanted to tell my with that comment.

Comment: @ByteCommander oh sorry I guess I didn't read your whole comment. I tried using 7z but can't seem to get it to extract to the directory successfully. I guess I could do the mount but I'm trying to right this as close to native python as possible.